# Razor Syntax for SWITCH

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code for SWITCH statement (Razor - ASP.NET MVC). It is giving syntax error. Can you provide me the correct syntax code ?

```
@switch (DateTime.Now.Hour)
{
    case < 12: // ERROR HERE
        message="Morning.";
        break;
    case > 12: // ERROR HERE
        message="Evening.";
        break;
    default:
        message="Afternoon";
        break;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't apply condition in case statement.

Comment: Use nested if condition for this because switch case useful for match same value without condition use. use nested if for your case.

Answer (score 2):

> Use this for solve your problem

```
 if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
    {
        message="Morning.";
    }
    else if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 12)
    {
        message="Evening.";
    }
    else
    {
        message="Afternoon";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have expression evaluation in switch case.
It is **not possible.**

You need to use `if` `else` to achieve what you desire here.

Comment: I edited my question. Errors are throwing at those two lines. - Thanks